# Grouping an array from firestore in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database that has a number of orders in a restaurant app. I want to group these orders by the table number so as to present the user with a bill/check for each table number.

I have spent a lot of time researching it and I believe I need to using Dictionary and Grouping. As you will see from the code below I have made an attempt which I think might be close.

Here is how my data is structured in firestore:

[image: firestore data]

Here is my bill struct:

```
import Foundation


struct Bill {


var billID: String
var userID: String
var tableNumber: String
var itemsOrdered: [[String: Any]]


}
```

And here is my main view controller:

```
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import UIKit

class BillsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var billTable: UITableView!

    var billsArray = [Bill]()
    var groupedBills = [[Bill]]()

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    func getData() {
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        db.collection("Orders")
            .whereField("User_ID", isEqualTo: userID)
            .whereField("Order_Complete", isEqualTo: true)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    self.billsArray.removeAll()
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let userID = document.get("User_ID") as! String

                        let tableNumber = document.get("Table_Number") as! String
                        let docID = document.documentID
                        let itemsOrdered = document.get("Items_Ordered") as! [[String: Any]]

                        let bill = Bill(billID: docID, userID: userID, tableNumber: tableNumber, itemsOrdered: itemsOrdered)

                        self.billsArray.append(bill)
                    }
                }
                let groupedDictionaryInFunc = Dictionary(grouping: self.billsArray) { (bill) -> String in
                    bill.tableNumber
                }

                print(self.groupedBills)

                let keys = groupedDictionaryInFunc.keys.sorted()
                print("Keys\(keys)")
                keys.forEach {
                    self.groupedBills.append(groupedDictionaryInFunc[$0]!)
                }
            }

        billTable.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("From table func: \(groupedBills)")
        return groupedBills[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "billCell", for: indexPath)

        let bill = groupedBills[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(bill.itemsOrdered)"
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return groupedBills.count
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getData()

        billTable.delegate = self
        billTable.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

The expected (or desired!) result is it populates my tableview with each section title the table number and then the the contents of the section being the items that were ordered.

Currently I'm getting a blank and my grouped array appears to be empty.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear why you would need a Dictionary or grouping. It looks like you're storing the table number with the food order so.... if this *I want to group these orders by the table number* is your goal, why not query Firestore by tableNumber to get just the items for that table?

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your response. I potentially could have many tables and may not know the name of them if the user added a new table. How would I know which tables to query firestore for? The only method I could think of similar to what you suggest is querying just the table numbers that are attached to complete orders, putting them in an array then querying that array back for the ordered items map. But that sounds even more complex?

Comment: Sounds like you may be overcomplicating it. If it's a restaurant, they will have pre-set table numbers. All orders are attached to a table number so what I suggested above would work. But you're saying 'added a new table' - what does that mean in the context of a restaurant that has 20 tables, number 1 through 20. When would they 'add a new table'?

Comment: @Jay I'm almost definitely overcomplicating it :). The restaurant has the option (which will be rare) to add or delete tables. I've kept this in a "tables" collection along with the restaurant ID. I could pull this in to an array but then wouldn't I need to query firebase for each table number so `.whereField("Table_No", isEqualTo: myTableArray)`. Wouldn't that be overkill? Or am I completely misunderstanding?

Comment: Not sure why you would need to query for each table number or why you need an array for anything. What I get from your question is; you want to know what food/beverage items go to table 1. So you query for items where table = 1. Is there something more?

Comment: @Jay My end results is I would like a tableview that displays the table number as the section header and then the cells as all the items they have ordered. The complexity is that I expect many orders (think rounds of drinks) to be made but only one bill/check per table at the end. So a table may place 4 orders (each creating a document) before paying. I need the orders separate as my other view controller updates with the newest orders as they come in. The other element is there are many restaurants that could have any number of tables. Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Right. If you query for table 1 orders, those orders will be returned along with the child data (the ordered items). Table numbers are the section headers and the items for that table are the 'child' rows underneath each section. Section 1 is table 1 and then two people have 2 rounds of beer, so there would be 4 child rows, or however you want to organize the child data. Still not sure where the issue is; it sounds like you're on the right track. The number or restaurants or tables is not relevant to this particular function. Perhaps I am just not understanding the functionality.

Comment: @Jay Yes that is what I want. The closest I can get is using the grouping method. The table numbers as the headers (correct) but then the child rows is just the number of orders (rather than the total number of items ordered). Example: `Bill(billID: "abc", userID: "123", tableNumber: "18", itemsOrdered: [["itemName": Fosters, "itemQty": 5, "itemPrice": 2.35], ["itemQty": 1, "itemPrice": 2.47, "itemName": Fosters], ["itemQty": 2, "itemPrice": 2.55, "itemName": Carling]])]` is my first table with 1 order + 3 items. But I can't get the rows to equal the number of items

Comment: I can't really read that. Please put code and structures in the question, formatted so it's readable.